# Is my Riemann Sum correct?

Tags: calculus, integration

For the integral: $$\int_{-1}^{5} \left( x^{2} -4 \right) dx$$

My calculations:

$$\begin{align*}\Delta x &= \frac6n\\\\
x_i &= -1 + \frac{6i}n\\\\
f(x_i) &= 1 + \frac{36i^2}{n^2} -4\\\\
A&=72
\end{align*}$$

I'm unsure if this is correct as it is my first attempt at doing this type of problem.

Comment: Please check my transcription of your algebraic expressions; I wasn't sure where the $-4$ in the $f(x_i)$ expression was supposed to go.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you for fixing that for me. You fixed it correctly (-4 is in the correct spot)

Comment: The $-4$ does not seem right. If you expanded $\bigl(-1+{6i\over n} \bigr)^2$, you should have obtained $1+{36i^2\over n^2}-{12i\over n}$.

Comment: @DavidMitra Thank you for pointing that out, it seems I accidentally removed it when editing the latex. Added the -4 back to the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your integrand is $x^2-4$, then $\displaystyle f(x_i) = x_i^2 - 4 = \left( - 1 + \frac{6i}{n} \right)^2 - 4 = -3 -\frac{12i}{n} + \frac{36 i^2}{n^2}$,

where your $\displaystyle \Delta x = \frac6n$. Your integral then becomes :
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^{5} \left(x^2 -4 \right) dx = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \left(f(x_i) \times \Delta x \right) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \left(f(x_i) \times \frac{6}{n} \right)
\end{align}
$$
Hence, all we need is to evaluate $\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \left(f(x_i) \times \frac{6}{n} \right)$ and take the limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

$$
\begin{align}
\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \left(f(x_i) \times \frac{6}{n} \right) & = 6 \times \displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \left( \frac{-3}n - \frac{12i}{n^2} + \frac{36i^2}{n^3} \right)\\
& = 6 \times  \left(-3 - \frac{12 n(n-1)/2}{n^2} + \frac{36 n(n-1)(2n-1)/6}{n^3} \right)\\
& = 6 \times \left( -3 - 6 \frac{n-1}{n} + 12 \frac{(n-1)(n-1/2)}{n^2} \right)
\end{align}
$$
where we made use of the following summations.
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} 1 = n
$$
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} i = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}
$$
and
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} i^2 = \frac{n(n-1)(2n-1)}{6}
$$

Now taking the limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$, we get $$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \left(f(x_i) \times \frac{6}{n} \right) & = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} 6 \times \left( -3 - 6 \frac{n-1}{n} + 12 \frac{(n-1)(n-1/2)}{n^2} \right) \\
& = 6 \times \left( -3 - 6 + 12 \right) = 6 \times 3 = 18
\end{align}
$$
Hence,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^{5} x^2 dx = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \left(f(x_i) \times \frac{6}{n} \right) = 18
\end{align}
$$

---

**EDIT**:

Note that if $f(x) = x^2$ and $\displaystyle x_i = - 1 + \frac{6i}{n}$, then $\displaystyle f(x_i) = x_i^2 = \left( - 1 + \frac{6i}{n} \right)^2 = 1 -\frac{12i}{n} + \frac{36 i^2}{n^2}$ where your $\displaystyle \Delta x = \frac6n$. Your integral then becomes :
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^{5} x^2 dx = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \left(f(x_i) \times \Delta x \right) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \left(f(x_i) \times \frac{6}{n} \right)
\end{align}
$$
Hence, all we need is to evaluate $\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \left(f(x_i) \times \frac{6}{n} \right)$ and take the limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

$$
\begin{align}
\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \left(f(x_i) \times \frac{6}{n} \right) & = 6 \times \displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \left( \frac1n - \frac{12i}{n^2} + \frac{36i^2}{n^3} \right)\\
& = 6 \times  \left(1 - \frac{12 n(n-1)/2}{n^2} + \frac{36 n(n-1)(2n-1)/6}{n^3} \right)\\
& = 6 \times \left( 1 - 6 \frac{n-1}{n} + 12 \frac{(n-1)(n-1/2)}{n^2} \right)
\end{align}
$$
where we made use of the following summations.
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} 1 = n
$$
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} i = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}
$$
and
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} i^2 = \frac{n(n-1)(2n-1)}{6}
$$

Now taking the limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$, we get $$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \left(f(x_i) \times \frac{6}{n} \right) & = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} 6 \times \left( 1 - 6 \frac{n-1}{n} + 12 \frac{(n-1)(n-1/2)}{n^2} \right) \\
& = 6 \times \left( 1 - 6 + 12 \right) = 6 \times 7 = 42
\end{align}
$$
Hence,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^{5} x^2 dx = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \left(f(x_i) \times \frac{6}{n} \right) = 42
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I apologize, when the latex was fixed, the function was changed. The -4 was removed. I added it back. I think this may change the answer, as its where I got the -4 from

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It put me back on the right track and you showed me the formula.

Comment: When you put the final answer, should it also include the -4?  Also, are there shorter methods to getting these answers rather than using Riemanns Sum?

Answer (score 1):

Your $\Delta x$ and $x_i$ are fine, but you've gone astray after that: $$f(x_i)=x_i^2=\left(-1+\frac{6i}n\right)^2=1-\frac{12i}n+\frac{36i^2}{n^2}\;.$$ Your Riemann sum is then

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^n\left(1-\frac{12i}n+\frac{36i^2}{n^2}\right)\frac6n&=\frac6n\sum_{i=1}^n\left(1-\frac{12i}n+\frac{36i^2}{n^2}\right)\\
&=\frac6n\left(\sum_{i=1}^n1-\frac{12}n\sum_{i=1}^ni+\frac{36}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^ni^2\right)\\
&=\frac6n\left(n-\frac{12}n\cdot\frac{n(n+1)}2+\frac{36}{n^2}\cdot\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1}6\right)\\
&=\frac6n\left(n-6(n+1)+\frac{6(n+1)(2n+1)}n\right)\\
&=\frac6n\cdot\frac{-5n^2-6n+12n^2+18n+6}n\\
&=6\left(7+\frac{12}n+\frac6{n^2}\right)\;,
\end{align*}$$

which converges to $42$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: I apologize, when I edited the latex, it removed -4 from the function. I added it back.

Comment: Thank you for the reply and the explanation. It was easy to follow and made it easy to understand. (I did it the same way you did, however I just didn't square my value correctly)